# refresh ajax function after remove

Tags: ajax

I have a strange situation. After I delete by ajax some rows from a table, and got button which reloads via an ajax function (getlist) I still have this row in the table, I need to reload browser then this row is not any more on list. How to reload list proper to get result after delete row?

```
<script>
function getlist () {
$('#getlist').html("<center>Pobieram dostępną listę analiz...</center>");
// Do an ajax request

$.ajax({
  url: "views/getjoblist.php",
}).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
  $('#getlist').html(data); // display data

});
}
$('#getlist-reload').on('click', getlist);
getlist();

</script>
```

in other page I make delete with ajax POST:

```
<script>
 $('.table').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    job = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'views/delete.php',
            data: { jobname : job },
 
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is an AJAX issue, not a PHP issue if the problem is to do with client-side issues.

Comment: any sugestions ?

Comment: now i see after couple of minutes, this reload works, can cache do something ? there is way to turn this cache of or on reload clear `em ?

Comment: ok solved, in ajax getlist function need to add: cache: false, and is load evertime fresh content

Comment: Yes sometimes you need to hard refresh your page to see changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the cache. I suggest you set the HTTP header "Last-Modified" in the HTTP response header and the browser will automatically refresh the cache if it older.